# Ruby on Rails - SQLITE3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, erd

I have question about my project. I am creating a small project on fuel prices, where users enter the current price of fuel. To enter the price, go to: petrol_station -> post_date -> post. In post, there are two input fields: diesel_price and pb_price. This is my post in database. But I have this error when I try to add price (post).

I've tried deleted "NOT NULL" from db/schema. I tried also changing my ERD schema, but I think I have got everything what is obligatory.

Here is my ERROR:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation in PostsController#create
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: posts.petrol_station_id
Extracted source (around line #32):
    respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to [@petrol_station, @post_date], notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
```

Here is my repository:

> https://github.com/FilipK00/p-aplikacje-mobilne

Here is my ERD schema:
[erd_schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41An9.png)

Comment: you still have (https://github.com/FilipK00/p-aplikacje-mobilne/blob/main/db/schema.rb#L35) `not null` in your posts table. reset db and run migrations again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The param `petrol_station_id` is going outside the hash for **post** params:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "post"=>{"pb_price"=>"1", "diesel_price"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Post", "petrol_station_id"=>"1", "post_date_id"=>"1"}
```

This is the reason for the NOT NULL error, it tries to save a nil value in the `petrol_station_id` for the Post.

Since you search for the `PetrolStation` in the beginning of the create action:

```
@petrol_station = PetrolStation.find(params[:petrol_station_id])
```

Adding the code below `@post = @post_date.posts.new(post_params)` should do the job:

```
@post.petrol_station_id = @petrol_station.id
```

Comment: I've added your line of code, but I can't display this value now.

Comment: What do you mean can't display the value? Please add a line of code or explain a little more of what is happening.